# Kendo Ui disable column if radio checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I had `yesnoCheck()` function on my grid. Any idea how to disable `Status Date` column if column `status` is '**No**' and set value to null? [demo here](https://dojo.telerik.com/EtuFEKUz)

```js
var grid = $('#grid').kendoGrid({
  dataSource: dataSource,
  editable: "inline",
  toolbar: [{ name: "create", text: "Add" }],
  columns: [        
    { field: "status", title: "Status", editor: statusActive,
      template: data => data.status == "y" ? "Yes" : "No" },

    { field: "statusDate", title: "Status Date", format:"{0:MM-dd-yyyy}", editor: statusEditor },

    { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "&nbsp;" }
  ]
});

function statusActive(container, options) {
   $('<input class="k-radio" onclick=yesnoCheck(); id="radio1" name="status" type="radio" value="y" >').appendTo(container);
   $('<label class="k-radio-label" for="radio1">Yes&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>').appendTo(container); 
   $('<input class="k-radio" onclick=yesnoCheck(); id="radio2" name="status" type="radio" value="n" >').appendTo(container);
   $('<label class="k-radio-label" for="radio2">No</label>').appendTo(container);
}

function yesnoCheck(){
  if(document.getElementById('radio2').checked){ //if status is NO
    //disable column "Status Date" and set the value=''
  }
}
```

Comment: update, but seem still not working [update demo](https://dojo.telerik.com/EtuFEKUz/3)

Answer (score 0):

While binding your function yesnoCheck pass argument this, then you can access the your radio and datepicker too.
here the code

```
function statusActive(container, options) {
   $('<input class="k-radio" onclick=yesnoCheck(this); id="radio1" name="status" type="radio" value="y" >').appendTo(container);
   $('<label class="k-radio-label" for="radio1">Yes&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>').appendTo(container); 
   $('<input class="k-radio" onclick=yesnoCheck(this); id="radio2" name="status" type="radio" value="n" >').appendTo(container);
   $('<label class="k-radio-label" for="radio2">No</label>').appendTo(container);
}

function yesnoCheck(args){
  var datepicker =$($(args).closest("td").next('td').find(".k-datepicker input")).data("kendoDatePicker");
  if(document.getElementById('radio1').checked){ //if status is YES

      datepicker.enable();
  }else{
      datepicker.enable(false);
    //disable column "Status Date" and set the value=''
  }
}
```

Once you have datepicker access you can call any of the APIs.
Here is [Demo](https://dojo.telerik.com/EtuFEKUz/16)

Comment: it see not working. am I doing right?  [Demo here](https://dojo.telerik.com/EtuFEKUz/10)

Answer (score 0):

Finally after long hours seeking for the answer. Actually the answer is right here in the documentation [here](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/datepicker/api)

Here what I am looking for. [I update a working demo here if someone needed.](https://dojo.telerik.com/iPoFOjOL)

```js
function statusActive(container, options) {
   $('<input class="k-radio" onchange="disableColumn()" id="radio1" name="status" type="radio" value="y" >').appendTo(container);
   $('<label class="k-radio-label" for="radio1">Yes&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>').appendTo(container); 
   $('<input class="k-radio" onchange="disableColumn()" id="radio2" name="status" type="radio" value="n" >').appendTo(container);
   $('<label class="k-radio-label" for="radio2">No</label>').appendTo(container);
}

function disableColumn(){
  var datepicker = $("#statusDate").data("kendoDatePicker");
  if(document.getElementById('radio2').checked){ 
    datepicker.enable(false); 
    datepicker.value("");
  }else{
    datepicker.enable(true);
  }
}
```